# Select not unique in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

found some examples to search for double entries but they didn't work for me with checksums. What is wrong in that approach ?

```
$arrDouble = "37B8525F4EE3571AA43F0F61C64060D5", "37B8525F4EE3571AA43F0F61C64060D5", "1E7100E795F6B84778EE0C6795AC8E32"
$HashesUnique = $arrDouble | Select-Object -Unique
$HashesDouble = $arrDouble | Where-Object {$_.count -gt 1}
$HashesUnique
$HashesDouble
```

is there any NOT for Select-Object -Unique or Get-Unique ?
Unique works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should get you the duplicate hashes:

```
$arrDouble = "37B8525F4EE3571AA43F0F61C64060D5", "37B8525F4EE3571AA43F0F61C64060D5", "1E7100E795F6B84778EE0C6795AC8E32"

$hashesDouble = ($arrDouble | Group-Object | Where-Object Count -gt 1).Group | Select-Object -Unique

$hashesDouble
```

The output should be a list of hashes that appear more than once in `$arrDouble`:
`37B8525F4EE3571AA43F0F61C64060D5`

Comment: did work nicely, thanks